# Leader election with Spring Boot Cloud: Duplicate bean kubernetesHealthIndicator

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, spring-cloud-kubernetes, leader-election, fabric8-kubernetes-client

I'm trying to add leader election to a Spring Boot 3.2 service running on a local Kubernetes cluster. The [manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-kubernetes/reference/leader-election.html) advises to add the `spring-cloud-kubernetes-fabric8-leader` dependency, so now I have

```
implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-kubernetes-fabric8-leader:3.1.0'
implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap:4.1.0'
implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-client-config:3.1.0'
```

This is too much, since on startup I get the error

```
The bean 'kubernetesHealthIndicator', defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/kubernetes/fabric8/Fabric8ActuatorConfiguration.class], could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/kubernetes/client/KubernetesClientActuatorConfiguration.class] and overriding is disabled.
```

Sure, both `spring-cloud-kubernetes-fabric8-leader` and `spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-client-config` define this. I seem to need both dependencies - so what should I do? Btw: These are the only `spring-cloud` dependencies of the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that `spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-*` and `spring-cloud-kubernetes-fabric8-*` are not really compatible (and this is not properly documented).

Changing the dependencies to

```
implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-kubernetes-fabric8-leader:3.1.0'
implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap:4.1.0'
implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-fabric8-config:3.1.0'
```

solved this for me.

Comment: if you think this is improperly documented, go to github of the project and open and issue. We will fix it and discuss further over there. thank you